# Automatic Toggle between open tabs in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet, internet-explorer-10

Currently I am using Internet Explorer 10, and I have 4 displays opened.
Let it be Tab1, Tab2, Tab3 and Tab4.
So I need to Automatically toggle from Tab1 to Tab2 then to Tab3 and so on.
We are keeping this machine for monitoring puprose,
No one would be accessing the machine once all the required Tabs are opened

Comment: Your looking for CTRL+TAB

Answer (score 4):

This may come a little late; but, I recently had a similar need.  Hope it helps  anyone else.

I am running the script below in Powershell to rotate through tabs in a Chrome browser (just change the "AppActivate" piece for your browser), for a system monitor setup.  Hope it helps...

```
while(1 -eq 1){
  $wshell=New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
  $wshell.AppActivate('Google Chrome');
  Sleep 5;
  $wshell.SendKeys('^{PGDN}');
}
```

--Charles

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer does not have this functionality built in or a native add on that could provide it.

If you have to use Internet Explorer you could use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and create a script like the one below to perform an automatic toggle between tabs every second.

```
Pwb :=  ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
Pwb.Visible:=True
Pwb.Navigate("Tab1URL")
Pwb.Navigate("Tab2URL", 2048)
Pwb.Navigate("Tab3URL", 2048)
Pwb.Navigate("Tab4URL", 2048)   

Loop 10
{
    Send, ^{tab}
    Sleep, (1000)
}

^!p::Pause  ; Press Ctrl+Alt+P to pause. Press it again to resume.
```

If you are allowed to use Firefox than the easier option is to use an extension called [Tab Slideshow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-slideshow/) that will cycle through each tab after a set amount of time. I believe this extension is also available on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

We use a handy tool called "Vue Pilot" that does what you want. You can create rotation lists that are synchronised between all your screens and manage them from an online interface.

We run a number of large screens around our office using it.

Find it here: https://www.vuepilot.com

Answer (score -1):

We are developing a product that you might find useful for this. It's called [Screensaver Ninja](https://Screensaver.Ninja) and it's a screensaver that displays several web pages one after the other. It'll be available for both Windows and Mac.

We don't believe using a full screen web browser is an adequate solution for an office/public dashboard, we wrote a blog post about it here:
https://screensaver.ninja/2015/02/18/not-just-full-screen-browser/

Screensaver Ninja maintains independent sessions from your browser and its feature rich configuration tool allows you to log in into those pages that require that:

[image]